# THREE.js - Differences between BufferGeometry vs merged geometry?

Tags: three.js, geometry, buffer-geometry

I understand that BufferGeometry is computationally more efficient.
I also understand that a merged geometry is efficient because it makes 1 render call.
Also I believe a merged geometry is easier to create/implement (for novices like me).

What other major and minor differences are there?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, merging geometry and buffergeometry can be used together.

Buffergeometry is memory efficient way of describing a model.
A merged (Buffer)Geometry on the other hand is a way to make several similar models to be drawn at the same time. This has the problem that moving 1 model inside the the merged geometry is more intensive. So this is normaaly used on static objects.

Comment: I thought it was possible to merged different geometries together.